# Could not find file 'C:\windows\system32\conhost.exe'

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file, console, windows-10

I am making a script to get the MD5 hash value of `C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe` but the file cannot be found by the scripts.

I have use batchfile, powershell, windows console app, and windows forms app but all of it are returning error:

> File not found.

I have check the file with Windows Explorer and it's there and not hidded.
I am using administrator account when running the scripts and apps.
I am running the script in Windows 10 LTSB 2016

Here is my wndows forms code:

```
// Replace this with the path to the file you want to hash
string filePath = @"C:\windows\system32\conhost.exe";

// Create an instance of the MD5 hash algorithm
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    // Open the file and compute the hash
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        var hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(stream);

        // Convert the hash to a string representation
        var hashString = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "");

        // Set the label text to the hash value
        label1.Text = hashString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to build 64-bit application.

Comment: With Powershell, you can use the cmdelt `Get-FileHash` in one line :
`$(Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe).Hash`

Answer (score 0):

With [Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.3) in Powershell

```
$(Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe).Hash
```

Answer (score 0):

The implication is that your application is a 32-bit application running on a 64-bit system.

On 64-bit systems, 32-bit applications see a *different* directory as `C:\Windows\System32`, and that directory does *not* contain a `conhost.exe` file.

However, you can refer to the 64-bit SYSTEM32 directory via the virtual `SysNative` directory (which only exists for 32-bit processes; by contrast, the virtual `SysWOW64` directory, which refers to the 32-bit SYSTEM directory, is visible to *both* 32-bit and 64-bit processes).

The following constructs the correct path depending on the bitness of the process.

```
string filePath = 
 $@"C:\Windows\{ (Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "System32" : "SysNative") }\conhost.exe";
```

---

As shown in [Hackoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76170419/45375),
*from PowerShell* [`Get-FileHash`](https://www.bing.com/) offers a more convenient way to compute the desired hash.